# Extracting "hidden" data from expanding/collapsing pivot table - Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm not sure if this is possible but as you can see I have a pivot table with multiple dependent and expandable fields. I am trying to concatenate the data from columns A:D into one cell which works fine in row 2 but doesn't work with blank parent cells, as you can see in column F.

Any ideas for how to achieve this?

**Pivot table**

[image: pivottable]

Comment: Have you tried `PivotTable Tools` > `Design` > `Report Layout` > `Repeat All Item Labels`, or do you want the PivotTable to remain showing the blanks?

Comment: why not to work with the data source of your pivot table? Transform the data into another table, in a way that you only get distinct rows of all possible occurences of panel | category | skill | Level. You may use [Get & Transform](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/get-transform-in-excel-2016-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de) for that.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you don't want to just Repeat All Item Labels in the PivotTable from the "Report Layout" drop-down on the Pivt Table Tools "Design" tab.

A formula to get the first non-blank value on or above the same row as the current cell from Column B can be constructed with a combination of `AGGREGATE`, `SUMPRODUCT` and `OFFSET`, like so:

```
=OFFSET($B2,SUMPRODUCT(AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($B$1:$B$100)*--(ROW($B$1:$B$100)<=ROW())*--(LEN($B$1:$B$100)>0),1))-ROW(),0)
```

### How does it work?

Starting with the outermost part, `OFFSET($B2, VALUE, 0)` - this will start in cell `B2`, then look up or down by `VALUE` rows to get the value.

Next we need to know *how many* rows we will need to look up-or-down.  Now, if we can work out the bottom-most row with data, we can subtract the current `ROW()` from that, giving us `OFFSET($B2, NON_BLANK-ROW(),0)`

So, to finish up we need to work out which rows are not blank, AND which rows are on-or-above our current row, then take the largest of those.  This is going to take an ArrayFormula, but we can use `SUMPRODUCT` to make that calculate properly.  To find the largest number we *could* use `MAX` or `LARGE` - but we get less errors if we pick `AGGREGATE(14,6,..,1)`.  (The `14` means "we want the *k*th largest number", the `6` means "ignore error values", and the `1` is *k* - so "we want the largest number, ignoring errors")

But, what list of numbers are we going to look at, I don't hear you ask.  Well, we want the `ROW` for output from our range (I'm using `$B$1:$B$100`, because using the whole column B would take *far* to long to calculate repeatedly), a comparison against the current `ROW()`, and check that the `LEN`gth is > 0.  Those last two are comparisons, so let's write them out first:

```
ROW($B$1:$B100)<=ROW()
```

and

```
LEN($B$1:$B$100)>0
```

We want to use `--` to convert `TRUE` and `FALSE` to `1` and `0` - this means that any "bad" values become 0, and any "good" values are larger than 0:

```
ROW($B$1:$B$100)*--(ROW($B$1:$B$100)<=ROW())*--(LEN($B$1:$B$100)>0)
```

This gives us the Row number when the Row is on-or-before the current row AND Column B is not blank - if either of those are False, then we get 0 instead.  Stick that in the `AGGREGATE` to find the largest number:

```
AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW($B$1:$B$100)*--(ROW($B$1:$B$100)<=ROW())*--(LEN($B$1:$B$100)>0), 1)
```

Then put it in a `SUMPRODUCT` to force Excel to treat it as an ArrayFormula, and that's your `NON_BLANK`.  This then gives you that first formula right at the top of the post